# Not able to retrieve methods once added in List<object> in c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am having a hard time understanding inheritance in C#. Suppose, i have two classes like this

```
public class Base
{
    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a BASE method");
    }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a DERIVED method");
    }
}
```

> now when i create a `List<object>` and try to add the two objects
>   like this and try to access the method, i am not able to do so

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        List<object> lists = new List<object>();
        lists.Add(new Base());
        lists.Add(new Derived());
        foreach (var a in lists)
        {

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

but when i add two integer value and try to access it, i am able to access it, how is this possible?

```
static void Main()
{
    List<object> lists = new List<object>();
    lists.Add(4);
    lists.Add(5);
    foreach (var a in lists)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

How am i able to get the integer value without even converting it, am i missing some key concept here, please help me understand

**UPDATE 1**

well let me try to explain my question one more time, when i want to call a method from the added lists i have to convert it to the respective type like this

```
A a = lists[0] as A;
B b = lists[1] as B;
C c = lists[2] as C;    
a.print();
b.print();
c.print();
```

but when i add int to the list like this

```
List<object> lists = new List<object>();
lists.Add(4);
lists.Add(5);
foreach (var a in lists)
{
Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

why is that there is no need to convert it first into int and then print it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept you are missing is `.ToString()` is overridden in `int` which makes it print the number instead of `System.Int32`. You can make your code do it too by simply adding a `public override string ToString()` to your functions.

```
public class Base
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "this is a BASE method";
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "this is a DERIVED method";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        List<object> lists = new List<object>();
        lists.Add(new Base());
        lists.Add(new Derived());
        foreach (var a in lists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

To actually be able to call `print()` you need to make your list of type `Base` instead of `object` and you need to mark the print function as `virtual` in base and `override` in the derived

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a BASE method");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a DERIVED method");
    }
}

static void Main()
{

    List<Base> lists = new List<Base>();
    lists.Add(new Base());
    lists.Add(new Derived());
    foreach (var a in lists)
    {
        a.print();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: i am aware of how to make this List<T> work in my example, but i am confused of how can an integer be printed without having the need to convert it first... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism allows you to call the correct method of a subclass even when using the base class type. However a restriction on this is that the type of class it is being set to must also have that method within it.

You are creating a list of `object` the `Object` class doesn't have the method you are trying to call inside of it and therefore you can not call that method. To rectify this you should change the list to the type that has that method (in this case `Base`).

Comment: do you mean to say that the object has the method of/for integer?

Comment: @LijinJohn The `Integer` class is using the overridden `toString()` method that is in the `Object` class. Your class does not override `toString()`

Comment: @LijinJohn No, yitzih's answer does not deal with your interger example in your question. He is only talking about how to fix your classes. Intiger uses somthing else

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you help me understand with some example, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` uses `ToString` when general `object` type is passed - that method is always available in any class.

You can override it in your case:

```
public class Base
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "this is a BASE method";
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "this is a DERIVED method";
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
foreach (var a in lists)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

`Integer` has overrided that method - that is why ir works.

Comment: `Integer` is not a class in .NET it is `System.Int32` or just `int` for short.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain could you help me understand the concept on how there was no conversion required while printing the integer... thank you

Comment: Because Console.WriteLine is written that it calls .ToString() when you pass in a object type. The ToString code does the conversion which is part of the int class. This answer shows how to make your class do it too.